# <a> tag results in multiple links sent to browser

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.Net MVC4 Razor website which I've built using the default template

The footer of the _Layout.cshtml page is as follows:

```
 <footer>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - BizTalkers ltd <a href="~/home/terms"/>Terms & Conditions</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

When this page renders in Chrome the hyperlink is presented twice, once where I would expect and then again below - but the 2nd time it appears as a blank line.

When I use "Inspect Element" from chrome I see the following:

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what I've done wrong? The website is http://www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk

Comment: It looks like Chrome is having trouble interpreting the self-closed <a> tag, and that's resulting in the extra <a> tag in the DOM (which is NOT showing up in the HTML source).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I inspected using Firefox, it turns out that you are not closing the `<a>` tag, and may be thats the culprit there. And you **CANNOT** self-close an `a` tag

So it should be

```
<p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - BizTalkers ltd 
   <a href="~/home/terms">Terms & Conditions</a> <-- Here
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `a`-tag is not closed. Try this:

```
<p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - BizTalkers ltd 
    <a href="~/home/terms"/>Terms & Conditions</a> <!-- add the end tag -->
</p>
```

Comment: @siride you cannot self close an `a` tag

Comment: @Mr.Alien: that's precisely the problem! And you still have an extra slash in your opening <a> tag.